# Is there any limit for micro SD card size in PI3?

Tags: pi-3

I have ordered Raspberry pi3. So I want what is the maximum compatible size of mirco sd card with PI3 ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Raspberry Pi 1B+, 2B, 3B is microSDHC card slot. This slot is compatible with maximum 32GB size.

@edit:
According to this [site](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards) there are microSDXC cards which works with microSDHC card slot and are bigger than 32GB, but not all of them works.

Thanks to [Ghanima](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/19949/ghanima).

Comment: Thanks Huczu. Do you know any official documentation on this and probably other limitations?

Comment: While not *official* there's some additional info, e.g. which cards do work and which don't [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards)

Comment: I have this one, Samsung Evo MB-MP64DA/EU - Tarjeta de memoria micro SDXC de 64 GB (UHS -I Grade 1, Clase 10, con adaptador SD), and it works in a Raspberry Pi 3 model B.

Comment: tested several 64GB u10 mSD cards... all woking... a few sometimes are not recognized... but after a remove/re-insert they become 'convinced' to work...

Comment: I have a 128GB u10 mSD ready to test... (been testing it in a PC as a physical storage for VMs)... as soon as I can I will test it too with R-Pis... them 'feedback I will give!!! ;-)

Comment: "Because of a constraint in versions of SoC's used in the Raspberry Pi Zero, 1 and 2, the SD card partition size limit is 256GB. From the Raspberry Pi 3 onwards this limitation does not apply." Source: raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/sd-cards.md

Answer (score 6):

I'm using the SanDisk Ultra 128Gb for my RetroPie on the Pi 3

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B013UDL5HU/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Same here.  Can you confirm that you're able to use the entire space though?

Comment: I can confirm it has the entire space available. Using SanDisk 128Gb with official image.

Comment: "Because of a constraint in versions of SoC's used in the Raspberry Pi Zero, 1 and 2, the SD card partition size limit is 256GB. From the Raspberry Pi 3 onwards this limitation does not apply." Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/sd-cards.md