# Raspberry Pi does not boot properly after installing django

Tags: boot

I've a problem with my Raspberry Pi 3 model b.
My Raspberry Pi is supported with the latest version of raspbian.
The only thing I've added is an installation of django.

Problem is, it keeps hanging in the boot when i start my Raspberry Pi (as you see in the picture);

[image: keeps hanging on this]

The desktop screen really comes after several minutes and sometimes it doesn't do anything).
I did do a new installation of SD card and again installed Django.

There is only an empty project on.

Is it possible that django is too heavy for the Raspberry Pi, or has anybody else that had this problem?

For installation of django, i only installed this:

http://raspberrypituts.com/django-raspberry-pi-tutorial/

Really didn't do anything else. My SD card is brand new and 64g

Answer (score 1):

No, django is not too heavy for the pi, and this doesn't look like a heaviness oriented issue, it looks like a screw up.

There seems to be a lot more than just django included in that wham-bam tutorial. Maybe you should ditch that, do a bit more reading about django, install *just apache* and `pip` -- which should not require a `wget` from some git repo, BTW; I'm not a python user but I would think `apt install python-pip` is a better choice -- then go from there.

In fact you don't even need `pip`; there's a `python-django` (python 2.7) package and a `python3-djanjo` package already.  If you are just starting out with something, use with the distro packages whenever possible.  People who write "tutorials" like this which lead well off a beaten path without explaining the whys and where-fores should be themselves led off the trail and beaten ;)

I am sure there is plenty of much, much better quality material around, although it may not seem to promise wham-bam (oops...) results the same way.  The official python documentation is pretty thorough, and django has been around for a long time and is very widely used; presumably the same is true there (I'm not a user, but I sometimes peek my head in).  Your mistake is including "raspberry pi" in your search terms.  It's a fairly normal computer in this context (albeit a diminutive one), so it is not so much the brand of hardware that's relevant as the operating system, and Raspbian is a close derivative of **Debian GNU/Linux**, which has been around for several decades.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough rep points for a comment, So please feel free to change this into one

You have noted you have used a new 64 GB sd card.
According to [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=46447) not all cards > 32 GB are supported. My hunch is installing django is somehow triggering a corner case. You could try using a smaller card if you have one and see if the problem persists.

See [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45312/is-there-any-limit-for-micro-sd-card-size-in-pi3) too.

HTH