# Mounted USB to SSD drive locks up

Tags: usb, hard-drive, mariadb

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ with the official charger running Raspbian Stretch Lite (Debian Version 9.4, Kernal 4.14.34-v7+ #1110) with MariaDB (Version 10.1.23) and I am trying to import a 52GB SQL file.

To help with storage I have connected a 500GB Samsung SSD 750 EVO SATA disk via a [Sabrent USB 3.0 to SSD](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B011M8YACM) cable and added `safe_mode_gpio=4` to the end of the `/boot/config.txt` file and mounted the drive and copied the 52GB SQL onto it.

I then moved the MariaDB data folder onto the mounted drive and updated the `50-server.cnf` file with the new location of the data folder  `datadir=/mnt/Data/mysql` then restarted MariaDB:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select @@datadir;
+------------------+
| @@datadir        |
+------------------+
| /mnt/Data/mysql/ |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Despite all of that it the import consistently fails after importing around 1.2 GB of data:

```
pi@raspberrypidb:/mnt/Data/export $ sudo mysql -u root -p springbootdb < import.sql
Enter password: 
ERROR 2013 (HY000) at line 18939: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
pi@raspberrypidb:/mnt/Data/export $
```

Checking the `mysql.log` file shows a lot of waiting errors:

```
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 2280
--Thread 1463808832 has waited at buf0flu.cc line 1886 for 241.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x6ae589a0 '&buf_pool->flush_state_mutex', lock var 1
Last time reserved by thread 1535112000 in file not yet reserved line 0, waiters flag 1
--Thread 1455420224 has waited at buf0flu.cc line 1886 for 241.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x6ae589a0 '&buf_pool->flush_state_mutex', lock var 1
Last time reserved by thread 1535112000 in file not yet reserved line 0, waiters flag 1
--Thread 1501557568 has waited at log0log.cc line 1817 for 241.00 seconds the semaphore:
Mutex at 0x76107588 '&log_sys->mutex', lock var 1
Last time reserved by thread 1639392064 in file not yet reserved line 0, waiters flag 1
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 2237
Mutex spin waits 2347, rounds 54859, OS waits 1664
RW-shared spins 161, rounds 4581, OS waits 149
RW-excl spins 4, rounds 13329, OS waits 439
Spin rounds per wait: 23.37 mutex, 28.45 RW-shared, 3332.25 RW-excl

...

--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: complete io for buf page (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 1
3377 OS file reads, 94822 OS file writes, 6201 OS fsyncs
0 pending reads, 1 pending writes
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 0.00 writes/s, 0.00 fsyncs/s
```

Checking the `kern.log` file shows another timeout relating to my mounted disk:

```
INFO: task mount.ntfs:255 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
      Tainted: G         C      4.14.34-v7+ #1110
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
mount.ntfs      D    0   255      1 0x00000000
[<8079a0b8>] (__schedule) from [<8079a730>] (schedule+0x50/0xa8)
[<8079a730>] (schedule) from [<8079e314>] (schedule_timeout+0x1d0/0x3f4)
[<8079e314>] (schedule_timeout) from [<8079ac7c>] (io_schedule_timeout+0x28/0x48)
[<8079ac7c>] (io_schedule_timeout) from [<8079b62c>] (wait_for_common_io.constprop.2+0xc0/0x144)
[<8079b62c>] (wait_for_common_io.constprop.2) from [<8079b6e8>] (wait_for_completion_io+0x1c/0x20)
[<8079b6e8>] (wait_for_completion_io) from [<80465b48>] (submit_bio_wait+0x6c/0x78)
[<80465b48>] (submit_bio_wait) from [<804743d8>] (blkdev_issue_flush+0x94/0xbc)
[<804743d8>] (blkdev_issue_flush) from [<802c8930>] (blkdev_fsync+0x48/0x58)
[<802c8930>] (blkdev_fsync) from [<802c0418>] (vfs_fsync_range+0x68/0xc8)
[<802c0418>] (vfs_fsync_range) from [<802c0500>] (do_fsync+0x4c/0x74)
[<802c0500>] (do_fsync) from [<802c07d8>] (SyS_fsync+0x1c/0x20)
[<802c07d8>] (SyS_fsync) from [<80108060>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x28)
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x00 driverbyte=0x08
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 Sense Key : 0x2 [current] 
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 ASC=0x4 ASCQ=0x7 
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x35 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
```

In the `kern.log` file I also found this line rather suspicious:

```
EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JMicron                   4102 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
```

In an attempt to fix this lock I have tried setting `innodb_adaptive_hash_index=0` in `50-server.cnf` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24910831/1180825) and tried changing the dirty ratio as suggested [here](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/09/22/linux-kernel-panic-issue-fix-hung_task_timeout_secs-blocked-120-seconds-problem/):

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.dirty_ratio=10
sudo sysctl -w vm.dirty_background_ratio=5
sudo sysctl -p
```

The import runs fine if I move the MariaDB data folder back onto my 128GB microSD card but I am wanting to store more data which is why I am wanting to use a spare SSD instead of forking out a costly 400GB microSD card.

Is it possible my USB to SATA cable is not fully supported?

Comment: given that the Pi does not have USB3 ports that is very likely.

Comment: Can you try it with a powered USB2 hub? Btw: 400GB microSD are not supported, see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/45312/78211 . Related: ["How much current can draw from the USB ports"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/51616/78211)

Comment: I am going to try a different USB to SATA cable, the one sold here https://shop.pimoroni.com/products/sata-hard-drive-to-usb-adapter and hope that has better support. I don't have a USB2 Hub at hand but the new cable allows me to power it with a separate power source.  I am also using the official raspberry pi plug which should provide a steady 2.5A  https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-universal-power-supply/

Comment: "Power Consumption (W) Active Read/Write (Average): 2.3W / 2.5W* * Actual power consumption may vary depending on system hardware & configuration" source: https://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/ssd-750-evo-25-sata-500gb-mz-750500bw/